# Emacs dev builds for MS Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows

Is there anywhere I can download a pre-compiled executable of the Emacs development version, all built and ready to run on Windows?

Doesn't have to be a daily build. Anything from the last month or so would be fine.

Answer (score 4):

**emacsbinw64** and **emacs-bin** projects on sourceforge.net provide development and stable builds of emacs for Windows (both 32-bit and 64-bit versions).

### Emacs Snapshot builds for 64-bit Windows

*Built by Chris Zheng*

- [Download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/emacsbinw64) | [RSS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emacsbinw64/rss?path=/snapshot)<sup>1</sup> | [Homepage](http://emacsbinw64.sourceforge.net/)

From the homepage,

> - 100% unmodified source code from git master and release version.
> - Native 64-Bit binary for MS-Windows.
> - Compiled with optimization.
> - With JPEG, GIF, PNG, TIFF, SVG, XML2, and GnuTLS support.

### Emacs Snapshot builds for 32-bit Windows

*Built by Dani Moncayo*

- [Download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/emacs-bin) | [RSS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emacs-bin/rss?path=/snapshots)<sup>1</sup>

> Each package contains exactly what "make install" produces.
>   Therefore, even though they have support for optional libraries, the
>   binaries of those libraries are not bundled.

*As **lawlist** mentions in the comments, the 32-bit version does not come pre-packaged with PNG and other image support.*

---

<sup>1</sup> Get notified via your favorite RSS reader when a new build is available.

Comment: I believe the 32-bit will need the .dll files for images and so forth, but the 64-bit has the .dll included.

Comment: @lawlist I agree, `M-x` [`xkcd`](https://github.com/vibhavp/emacs-xkcd) does not work on the 32-bit version but works great on the 64-bit version.

Comment: @kaushalmod -- Here is a cheat-sheet if you'd like to build your own 32-bit version for Windows someday:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17040/2287

Comment: @lawlist Thanks. That's on my list of things to attempt. I have never built anything in Windows yet. So that procedure seems overwhelming at the moment :)

Comment: @kaushalmodi -- I just tried the latest build from Dani Moncayo -- `emacs-master-20151025@143907-bin-i686-mingw32.7z` and the .dll files from ezwinports, and the xkcd library works when I call the function `M-x xkcd-rand`.  I didn't try any other functions since I'm not familiar with that library -- I just was curious to see what happened.  The custom 32-bit build in the above-mentioned build-your-own link also worked with the function `M-x xkcd-rand`.

Comment: @lawlist Just so that I understand correctly, you need to simply copy the dll files from ezwinports into the `bin/` directory. Correct?

Comment: @kaushalmodi -- yes -- `M-x describe-variable RET dynamic-library-alist RET` -- for a listing of the .dll files.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one place:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/emacs-bin/

[Dani Moncayo](http://sourceforge.net/u/dmoncayo/profile/) provides these builds.

Comment: Check out the 64-build from the other answer if your machine supports it. It worked better for me.