# Where is official 64-bit Emacs for Windows? (The manual said there is!)

Tags: microsoft-windows

I usually download Emacs for Windows from the official GNU site:

http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/

The latest version is: `emacs-24.5-bin-i686-mingw32.zip`

I'm curious that why there's no 64-bit?

From the Emacs manual:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/efaq-w32.html

> 2.1 Where can I download Emacs?
>
> Pre-compiled versions are distributed from ftp.gnu.org mirrors. Emacs
>   binaries are distributed as zip files, digitally signed by the
>   developer who built them. Generally most users will want the file
>   `emacs-24.5-bin-i686-pc-mingw.zip` for the **32-bit** build, and
>   `emacs-24.5-bin-x86_64-w64-mingw32.zip` for the **64-bit** build. The zip
>   archive contains everything you need to get started.
>
> The latest source is available from ftp.gnu.org mirrors. It is
>   distributed as a compressed tar file, digitally signed by the
>   maintainer who made the release.
>
> The development version of Emacs is available from Savannah, the GNU
>   development site.

Since the manual said there's 64-bit, where is it?

**Update**

Here is the response from the debugs.gnu.org:

http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20851

Basically,

1. The FAQ docs is obsolete.
2. 64-bit Emacs on Windows is built by volunteers, and there's no such volunteer currently.
3. They've removed the obsolete docs from the Emacs repo. Web pages get updated at next release.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no **"official"** 64-bit Emacs version for Windows; however, there is a person enthusiastic about building a 64-bit version and I regularly receive notices that updates are avaiable -- see Drew's comment below for the link.  It comes with the necessary .dll files for viewing images.

Comment: @lawlist: To my knowledge also. And [here](http://emacsbinw64.sourceforge.net/) is one. OP: If you don't get a positive answer about an official one, consider filing a doc bug for that claim that there is one: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Great stuff - downloaded and works a treat.  Someone buy that man a pint!

Comment: @Drew Thank you. I downloaded the Emacs from your link. Just one small problem: There's no `runemacs.exe`, only `emacs.exe`, each time I run emacs, it would create a black console windows behind it. And if I close this console window, Emacs would quit. Any way to get rid of this black console?

Comment: @DaveF There's only `emacs.exe`, no `runemacs.exe` as in GNU official port. How do you get rid of the background console?

Comment: @Nick Strange, mine came with the normal `runemacs.exe` as usual, I think I clicked in Files/Release or something on SourceForge.

Comment: @DaveF Can you check your emacs version? `M-x emacs-version`, mine is `GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2015-06-04 on KAEL`

Comment: @Nick Mine says `GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2015-05-16 on KAEL`

Comment: @DaveF I went to that sourceforge site again and clicked on `Release`, found `emacs 24.5.1`. There's `runemacs.exe` as usual. Thank you very much. I also think bind the `apps key`(the key between right alt and right ctrl) to `M-x`, as the official emacs do, would save a lot of time: ` (global-set-key (kbd "<apps>") (lookup-key global-map (kbd "M-x")))`

Comment: @Nick: if you have found a satisfactory solution, please go ahead and post an answer to your own question.

Comment: @Dan Thank you for your reminding. I've sent a bug report just now. I've post the result here if I got any response. (Although I can use 64-bit Emacs on Windows, I still consider an official one is necessary, as stated in the Emacs manual. Anyway, I will put this solution as an answer.)

Comment: I found a [tutorial](http://sourceforge.net/p/emacsbinw64/wiki/Build%20guideline%20for%20MSYS2-MinGW-w64%20system/) for building it yourself.

Comment: @Nick There is no official build but you can get the links to the latest Emacs build for Windows (32/64) from this [emacs.SE answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10936/115).

Answer (score 22):

Courtesy of @Drew, here is a 64-bit Emacs for Windows:

http://emacsbinw64.sourceforge.net/

If you want a stable version, make sure download the **Release**, not latest version. From my experience, the latest version is Emacs 25.x, and there's no `runemacs.exe` in it.

(Please note this is not the official GNU version.)

As of November 2016, the author has also made it available on Github: https://github.com/zklhp/emacs-w64. The latest stable version is already 25.1

Comment: Downvoted: I think that sourceforge can no longer be relied upon as a reliable site for code / binary distribution. (See gimp, nmap and other account hijacking by sourceforge)

Comment: @MrBones It seems this is the only option we can find, or else we have to build from source. This port of 64-bit Emacs works fine with Dave F and me.

Comment: Sure, but the only option doesn't make it legit. I agree that it sucks, but I don't think sourceforge is an acceptable option.

Comment: @Squidly: Perhaps you should tell that to [zklhp](http://sourceforge.net/u/zklhp/)?

Comment: There are releases provided on GitHub: https://github.com/zklhp/emacs-w64/releases

Comment: Emacs has an official Windows distribution now, which should be preferred.

Answer (score 10):

As of December 2016, there is now a **64-bit version** of GNU Emacs for Windows on the official GNU downloads sites.

From the FAQ: [GNU Emacs FAQ for MS Windows](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/efaq-w32.html)

> At time of writing, the latest version of GNU Emacs is version 25.1.

For example, in one of the download sites, I notice the following file:

> /gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-25.1-2-x86_64-w64-mingw32.zip

It seems to be a 64 version. Also,  *Cygwin 64* also seems to have a 64-bit emacs-X11; if you update your packages in Cygwin, it should come over as the most-recent version.

Comment: They are a 64 bit version for sure. Also, for Emacs-25, there is a file with all the dependencies.

Comment: By now I've started using Emacs from Cygwin (yes it's 25 if you upgrade it).  If you're using a 64-bit Cygwin distribution, then the Emacs is 64-bit too.. it's working OK!

Answer (score 1):

[Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) seems to have a 64 bit emacs package - I can't evaluate it yet as I'm downloading it now..

Comment: It uses exactly the same source as `http://emacsbinw64.sourceforge.net/`