# How can I keep the emacs window at a constant size when hiding/showing the menu bar?

Tags: frames, microsoft-windows, menu-bar

I don't like to waste screen space, so usually I have the menu bar hidden. Sometimes, I'd like to show it nevertheless, so I have bound the "menu" key to menu-bar-mode. Works perfectly:

```
(global-set-key '[(apps)]                  'menu-bar-mode)
```

My emacs window is always maximised. That's no problem when showing the menu bar. But when I hide it again, the window is not maximised any more. It is resized and the height of the menu bar is missing :( Is there a way to prevent this?

To make it more complicated: I'm talking about native windows Emacs
(GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2015-05-16 on KAEL)

Comment: There were some issues with the frame size and menu bar on OSX a couple of months ago -- Martin and Anders made several improvements when working on feature request 21415.  If you can get a hold of a master branch build for Windows (and yes they do exist), see if that fixes the issue.  If not submit a bug report and Martin will no doubt take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try - could you give me a hint where to find a build?

Comment: Based on my sporadic review of the Emacs mail archives, I am confident that Dani has received at least some input from Eli regarding how to properly build Emacs for Windows:  https://sourceforge.net/projects/emacs-bin/  and if you want to build your own, I wrote a cheat-sheet:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16971/how-to-build-emacs-master-branch-aka-trunk-on-ms-windows  Dani's build will need the dll files if you want to view images out-of-the-box.  You don't need the dll for Emacs to work, but to view pdf and jpg and png and so forth, you will.

Answer (score 1):

The problem went away after I have updated to GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)