# msys2 emacs install not working?

Tags: microsoft-windows

I've tried to install Emacs on Windows (7) with msys2, however, I'm not sure if it worked. In any event, I can't find it on my machine. The install (following [these instructions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/download.html) seems to go fine -- but then no Emacs.

Comment: If you want a prebuilt binary, then just download it from a reliable source and click on `runemacs.exe` in the `bin` directory.  If you want to build it yourself, then here is a link to a couple of tutorials -- **How to build Emacs master branch (aka trunk) on MS-Windows** -- http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16971/how-to-build-emacs-master-branch-aka-trunk-on-ms-windows

Comment: Assuming you use a 64bit-Windows you can get really good builds from https://sourceforge.net/projects/emacsbinw64/ . You don't even have to install msys2 for that. :-) The official windows builds didn't work for me.

Comment: What do you mean you can't find it? If you installed it with msys2's pacman, it's in /mingw64/bin/emacs in msys' virtual filesystem. You can run it by typing "emacs" at the mysy2 prompt.

Answer (score 3):

If you have chosen all the default paths while installing msys (pacman), you can find 'emacs.exe' under   C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\   on your windows machine as the pacman command installs it under the same catalog as itself. Go there and double click 'emacs.exe' app to launch it. You can also right click on the executable file(emacs.exe) and pin it to either start or task bar for the future shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

```
# bash# pacman -Ss emacs
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-emacs 28.1-1 [installed]
    The extensible, customizable, self-documenting, real-time display editor (mingw-w64)
msys/emacs 27.2-1 (editors)
    The extensible, customizable, self-documenting, real-time display editor (msys2)

# where.exe runemacs.exe
C:\opt\msys64\mingw64\bin\runemacs.exe
```

Comment: `pacman -Ss emacs` -> `mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-emacs 28.2-2 [installed]`  
`$ where emacs` -> `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).`  
`$ where runemacs` -> `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).`

Comment: @DmitryAvtonomov You launched MSYS2 `mintty` while NT Emacs is installed in Mingw64 environment, Please launch `mingw64.exe` or update your `PATH`.

Comment: https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/ - answers your concerns.