# Missing features on Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, libraries

I am trying to assemble a list of features that work out of the box on Linux but will fail on a standard installation without addinng additional **executables** or **DLLs**, or are **not implemented** at all for Windows.

Specifically, I am interested in features supported directly by the **emacs lisp API** of a clean installation, potentially after updating packages from ELPA but not installing any new packages explicitly. Since there are inofficial binary releases like [Emacs-w64](http://emacsbinw64.sourceforge.net/), the official releases from [gnu.org](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/) should be the relevant point of reference.

More explicitly, this includes the following groups:

- Features lacking Windows-compatibility at the C-source level.

  The one I ran into is ImageMagick support for transforming images without calling exeternal commands, which silently fails on Windows.
- Libraries Emacs is normally linked against for binary Windows releases, whose corresponding DLL files are not shipped with Emacs (e.g. `libpng` or `libjpeg`).

  `dynamic-library-alist` should give a complete list of such libraries. Unless it is incomplete, or it may include entries for libraries that the binary was not actually compiled against, nothing should have to be said about these.
- Libraries which Emacs *could* be linked against, but isn't in the binary release (if there are any).
- Ubiquitous Linux tools which are not present on Windows, which the standard emacs-lisp API and builtin interactive commands depend on.

  The most important examples are probably `find` and `grep`.
- Executables required by extensions that are wide-spread enough to be now bundled with Emacs releases.

  An example would be `org-mode`, whose export feature requires a LaTeX distribution. It is also an example for the unimplemented ImageMagick dependence.

Comment: This question might be too open-ended right now ("list all of the missing features").  Instead, could you edit the question to ask how to enable specific features that you want?

Comment: Well, if you are willing to use Cygwin, then your missing features will be different. And then in Cygwin you might opt to/not to use X-server, which will also add to the discrepancy in limitations.

Comment: Here is a link to a write-up of how to build Emacs master branch from source (for Windows), including installing the standard DLL files and GnuTLS:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16971/how-to-build-emacs-master-branch-aka-trunk-on-ms-windows  And, there a few pre-built binary distributions that come with the DLL files already included and GnuTLS -- e.g., http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/windows/

Comment: @Dan At any given time the answer is well defined, and the feature set of Emacs changes much over a few years, so it should be within scope. Finding out how to enable a specific feature isn't a problem (unless it is simply not possible), but an overview of missing features would be helpful.

Comment: @wvxvw I used to, but due to a long list of issues cropping up when using Emacs through cygwin (slow and sometimes failing fork operations, no opening of files by drag-and-drop, ...) I stopped doing it this way.

Comment: Is it the intent of the original poster to exclude or include optional executables in the list of missing features?  E.g., TexLive, grep, ghostscript, core utilities, rar/unrar, 7zip, etc. -- many installed libraries rely upon the existence of said executables.   That list could conceivably be rather large.

Comment: @lawlist Not originally. But since the builtin emacs lisp modules also include dependencies on executables that *don't* come with emacs, it would be useful. I'll rephrase the question to be more clear.